# Gym accesories for less force for grip

Tags: weightlifting, strength, muscle, gym

I am new to weight exercise and don't know much about different accessories in gym, moreover i have problem in my pinki finger controlling muscle so i want to avoid tighter grips, I found [lifting hook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DVM34NO)

on internet, how effective are they do they reduce strain in forearm muscles and is there nay other accessorize to reduce grip force but still able to do biceps curl, or shoulder shrugs ?

Comment: Unless you have good medical advice telling you not to use your pinky finger for gripping, I would recommend skipping the "lifting hook" and using your hand.

Comment: I agree with @EricKaufman.  Consider using a [hook grip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_grip) instead of an accessory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your grip is limiting your ability to perform heavier lifts (like, for example, a heavy deadlift), then you should consider shifting to a hook grip [as suggested in the comments](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/34294/gym-accesories-for-less-force-for-grip#comment53453_34294), or you could use [lifting straps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013J4KIXW).

In any case, if you have a weak grip, the best thing you can do is perform specific exercises to strengthen it. Holding the weight at the end of the concentric portion of a deadlift for some time, for example. Now, if you want to spend your money in gym toys, you could buy some [Fat Gripz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FIS14Y) to help you with that.